# How can I match XML tags and attributes with a regular expression in Perl?

Tags: xml, regex, perl

What I need is something like this:

```
/<[\w\d]+ ([\w\d]+\=[w\d])+\/>/
```

Something that would match several attribute key/value pairs. Is that possible?

Comment: `<![CDATA[ <I am="not" xml="tag"/> ]]> <!-- <me:neither /> -->`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Ether: Actually you still can parse XML with Perl regular expressions, since Perl regular expressions are not regular either ;) But it is a task to accomplish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have much more succes using an XML parser, for example, [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Parser). Parsing XML using regular expressions is very difficult (impossible?) and unless your use case is trivial, a proper XML parser is the reliable solution.

Comment: Impossible without a question mark.  XML is not a regular language.  Of course, some implementations of 'regular expressions' actually match non-regular languages, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 6):

It may be possible for a very limited range of valid XML.  If you are trying to parse XML, I strongly recommend that you use a parser, rather than try to use regular expressions. [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) is a good general-purpose parser available from CPAN.

For further reading, see also: [XML parsing vs Regular expressions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=668353)