# Can't parse XML effectively using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def getWeather(city):

    #create google weather api url
    url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + urllib.quote(city)

    try:
        # open google weather api url
        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    except:
        # if there was an error opening the url, return
        return "Error opening url"

    # read contents to a string
    s = f.read()

    tree=ET.parse(s)

    current= tree.find("current_condition/condition")
    condition_data = current.get("data")  
    weather = condition_data  
    if weather == "<?xml version=":
        return "Invalid city"

    #return the weather condition
    #return weather

def main():
    while True:
        city = raw_input("Give me a city: ")
        weather = getWeather(city)
        print(weather)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

gives error , I actually wanted to find values from google weather xml site tags

Comment: Can you give the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063319/how-to-implement-python-to-find-value-between-xml-tags

Same question.

Comment: File "weatxml.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "weatxml.py", line 32, in main
    weather = getWeather(city)
  File "weatxml.py", line 18, in getWeather
    tree=ET.parse(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 579, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<?xml version="1.0"?><xml_api_reply version="1"><weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" ><forecast_informa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
tree=ET.parse(s)
```

try

```
tree=ET.fromstring(s)
```

Also, your path to the data you want is incorrect. It should be: weather/current_conditions/condition

This should work:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def getWeather(city):

    #create google weather api url
    url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + urllib.quote(city)

    try:
        # open google weather api url
        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    except:
        # if there was an error opening the url, return
        return "Error opening url"

    # read contents to a string
    s = f.read()

    tree=ET.fromstring(s)

    current= tree.find("weather/current_conditions/condition")
    condition_data = current.get("data")  
    weather = condition_data  
    if weather == "<?xml version=":
        return "Invalid city"

    #return the weather condition
    return weather

def main():
    while True:
        city = raw_input("Give me a city: ")
        weather = getWeather(city)
        print(weather)
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot 

but current=tree.find statement returns none 


structure of xml is as follows:


<current_conditions>

<condition data="Cloudy"/>

<temp_f data="97"/>

<temp_c data="36"/>

<humidity data="Humidity: 28%"/>

<icon data="/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif"/>

<wind_condition data="Wind: N at 0 mph"/>

Comment: @Harshit, the XML you show in your comment is not the actual XML that comes back from Google. The code that I gave you will work. Are you feeding it pretend data?

Comment: ya I got that thanks It worked Thanks once again You people rock

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the same answer here I did in my comment on your previous question. In the future, kindly update the existing question instead of posting a new one.

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063319/how-to-implement-python-to-find-value-between-xml-tags/3063471#3063471)

I'm sorry - I didn't mean that my code would work exactly as you desired. Your error is because s is a string and parse takes a file or file-like object. So, "tree = ET.parse(f)" may work better. I would suggest reading up on the ElementTree api so you understand what the functions I've used above do in practice. Hope that helps, and let me know if it works.

Comment: I made certain improvements in my code as below:

#rest of code same

s = f.read()

    tree=ET.fromstring(s)
    

    current= tree.find("current_conditions/condition")

    print current

    #condition_data = current.get("data")  

    #weather = condition_data  

    weather = current

    if weather == "<?xml version=":

        return "Invalid city"



    #return the weather condition

    return weather


#code is working but returns none

now below is the structure of xml file


<current_conditions>
<condition data="Cloudy"/>
<temp_f data="97"/>

Comment: it returns none although it has cloudy in it , dont know to update questions I am new here

Comment: I think none is coming because tree.find is not implemented correctly
following is the url 
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=london