# Really simple way to deal with XML in Python?

Tags: python, xml

Musing over a [recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063319/), I started to wonder if there is a *really simple* way to deal with XML documents in Python. A pythonic way, if you will.

Perhaps I can explain best if i give example: let's say the following - which i think is a good example of how XML is (mis)used in web services - is the response i get from http request to http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=94043

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
  <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" >
    <forecast_information>
      <city data="Mountain View, CA"/>
      <postal_code data="94043"/>
      <latitude_e6 data=""/>
      <longitude_e6 data=""/>
      <forecast_date data="2010-06-23"/>
      <current_date_time data="2010-06-24 00:02:54 +0000"/>
      <unit_system data="US"/>
    </forecast_information>
    <current_conditions>
      <condition data="Sunny"/>
      <temp_f data="68"/>
      <temp_c data="20"/>
      <humidity data="Humidity: 61%"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/>
      <wind_condition data="Wind: NW at 19 mph"/>
    </current_conditions>
    ...
    <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Sat"/>
      <low data="59"/>
      <high data="75"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
      <condition data="Partly Cloudy"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
  </weather>
</xml_api_reply>
```

After loading/parsing such document, i would like to be able to access the information as simple as say

```
>>> xml['xml_api_reply']['weather']['forecast_information']['city'].data
'Mountain View, CA'
```

or

```
>>> xml.xml_api_reply.weather.current_conditions.temp_f['data']
'68'
```

From what I saw so far, seems that `ElementTree` is the closest to what I dream of. But it's not there, there is still some fumbling to do when consuming XML. OTOH, what I am thinking is not that complicated - probably just thin veneer on top of a parser - and yet it can decrease annoyance of dealing with XML. Is there such a magic? (And if not - why?)

PS. Note I have tried `BeautifulSoup` already and while I like its approach, it has real issues with empty `<element/>`s - see below in comments for examples.

Comment: ElementTree is probably the best you have, without depending on a 3rd party library.

Comment: I think lxml.objectify is perfect solution for this question.

Comment: What you're looking for looks a lot like Perl's XML::Simple CPAN module, which works well for a lot of routine XML work. Someone feeling industrious could probably implement something similar as an etree wrapper.

Comment: See also the reference to the PicklingTools libraries in the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7531652/507544 - that allows you to map forward and back between XML and Python dictionaries, with various options for handling the complexities that arise.  That way you can also generate XML after you manipulate the data some.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want a thin veneer? That's easy to cook up. Try the following trivial wrapper around ElementTree as a start:

```
# geetree.py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class GeeElem(object):
    """Wrapper around an ElementTree element. a['foo'] gets the
       attribute foo, a.foo gets the first subelement foo."""
    def __init__(self, elem):
        self.etElem = elem

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        res = self._getattr(name)
        if res is None:
            raise AttributeError, "No attribute named '%s'" % name
        return res

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        res = self._getelem(name)
        if res is None:
            raise IndexError, "No element named '%s'" % name
        return res

    def _getelem(self, name):
        res = self.etElem.find(name)
        if res is None:
            return None
        return GeeElem(res)

    def _getattr(self, name):
        return self.etElem.get(name)

class GeeTree(object):
    "Wrapper around an ElementTree."
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.doc = ET.parse(fname)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.doc.getroot().tag != name:
            raise IndexError, "No element named '%s'" % name
        return GeeElem(self.doc.getroot())

    def getroot(self):
        return self.doc.getroot()
```

You invoke it so:

```
>>> import geetree
>>> t = geetree.GeeTree('foo.xml')
>>> t.xml_api_reply.weather.forecast_information.city['data']
'Mountain View, CA'
>>> t.xml_api_reply.weather.current_conditions.temp_f['data']
'68'
```

Comment: With this recpide, how to get `Blah` from this XML : `<a><b>Blah</b></a>` ? I tried `doc.a.b`  but this doesn't give Blah...

Comment: @Basj: This veneer doesn't support that. You could ask that as a separate question if you want an answer. Hint: you would have to change `__getattr__` to allow you to access either object properties _or_ subelements, and you would have to deal with the inevitable conflicts between the two (what if I had a method `text` and a sublement `text`, for example?). This may give you some insight as to why `ElementTree` does _not_ follow quite as simple a design as was demanded here...

Comment: THanks @OwenS for answer. I finally use : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10077069/1422096 , that's the best/simplest solution I have found among at least 10 others I tried

Comment: I chuckled at the notion that a "simple" way to deal with XML in Python 3 is to create a wrapper around ElementTree. The meaning of "simple" is obviously highly subjective...

Answer (score 19):

lxml has been mentioned. You might also check out [lxml.objectify](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify-module.html) for some really simple manipulation.

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> tree = objectify.fromstring(your_xml)
>>> tree.weather.attrib["module_id"]
'0'
>>> tree.weather.forecast_information.city.attrib["data"]
'Mountain View, CA'
>>> tree.weather.forecast_information.postal_code.attrib["data"]
'94043'
```

Comment: ++. Does what asked for, although like in the Amara case, free gorilla (a ton of non-distro library) comes with the order of banana. Btw, seems also can use `.get('data')` instead of `.attrib['data']`

Comment: But how does one "interrogate" an object returns by `objectivity`?  I mean, python `dictionary` has `.keys()` for example, but here it seems one need to know the structure and names a priory, no?  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Amara 2, particularly the Bindery part of [this tutorial](http://www.xml3k.org/Amara2/Tutorial).

It works in a way pretty similar to what you describe.

On the other hand. ElementTree's [find*()](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.find) methods can give you 90% of that and are packaged with Python.

Comment: I looked and indeed `amara.bindery` does what I am looking for - but it seems way too big (600k installer, 3MB source) - it's like someone said, I wanted a banana but now I got a "free" gorilla with it. Re ElementTree find*() - it's close but lacks that pythonic []/iterator veneer i was thinking about

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend lxml.etree and xpath to parse and analyse your data. Here is a complete example. I have truncated the xml to make it easier to read.

```
import lxml.etree

s = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml_api_reply version="1">
  <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" >
    <forecast_information>
      <city data="Mountain View, CA"/> <forecast_date data="2010-06-23"/>
    </forecast_information>
    <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Sat"/>
      <low data="59"/>
      <high data="75"/>
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
      <condition data="Partly Cloudy"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
  </weather>
</xml_api_reply>"""

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(s)
for weather in tree.xpath('/xml_api_reply/weather'):
    print weather.find('forecast_information/city/@data')[0]
    print weather.find('forecast_information/forecast_date/@data')[0]
    print weather.find('forecast_conditions/low/@data')[0]
    print weather.find('forecast_conditions/high/@data')[0]
```

Comment: Seems fairly easy indeed and i am taking note - but it is more xpath-ish (xpathologic?) than pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party library, then [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) will do almost exactly what you ask for:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulStoneSoup('''<snip>''')
>>> soup.xml_api_reply.weather.current_conditions.temp_f['data']
u'68'
```

Comment: I already looked at Beautiful[Stone]Soup - but it is **broken** (as documented http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html ) for empty tags like <element/> - which are aplenty in the example. For example `soup.xml_api_reply.weather.current_conditions.icon` returns `<icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"><wind_condition data="Wind: N at 25 mph"></wind_condition></icon>` or you can get `temp_c` via `soup.xml_api_reply.weather.current_conditions.condition.temp_f.temp_c['data']` which seems demented to me

Comment: It will work if 1) you know what empty tags you're looking for, and 2) they can be relied upon to be empty. Then you can specify them as an argument to the parser: selfClosingTags=['city','postal_code', ...]

Comment: @Owen S: <nod>, selfClosingTags indeed helped with the StoneSoup but one shouldn't have to do that really. The example is chock full of empty tags (that should have been attributes ... but aren't) - and so is the case in many XMLs

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the built in python xml module will do the trick.  Look at "xml.parsers.expat"

[xml.parsers.expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html#module-xml.parsers.expat)

Comment: A low-level SAXlike parser interface provides a Pythonic object interface to the parsed XML document?? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following [python-simplexml](http://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml) module, which in the attempts of the author to get something close to SimpleXML from PHP is indeed a `small wrapper around ElementTree`. It's under 100 lines but seems to do what was requested:

```
>>> import SimpleXml
>>> x = SimpleXml.parse(urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=94043'))
>>> print x.weather.current_conditions.temp_f['data']
58
```

Answer (score 0):

The suds project provides a Web Services client library that works almost exactly as you describe -- provide it a wsdl and then use factory methods to create the defined types (and process the responses too!).

Comment: Ok, that's interesting... but doesn't the name **suds** imply this is only for use with **SOAP**? The example above is not SOAPy and i won't want to go the slippery-SOAP. Also, where do I find WSDL of - for example - the weather service above?

Comment: Yes, you're right -- suds is definitely geared towards SOAP web-services rather than generic XML. A WSDL would be the published contract for that kind of service. My bad, I had assumed you had rinsed the bubbles from that example prior to posting :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking into the [DOM API for Python](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html). DOM is a pretty widely used XML interpretation system, so it should be pretty robust.

It's probably a little more complicated than what you describe, but that comes from its attempts to preserve all the information implicit in XML markup rather than from bad design.

Comment: The question is specifically for easy, pythonic XML access. DOM is many things (not _all_ of which are evil, I admit), but "easy" and "pythonic" it most certainly is _not_. Reverting to DOM for interacting with XML is like dropping to C (or worse, assembly) for a webapp -- it should be done rarely and only for remarkably good reason.

Comment: And I'd also like to note that's not because of preserving XML structure; it's because that library tries hard to adhere to a cross-language API for its interface. There are more Pythonic libraries that preserve the XML structure quite precisely.