# Is there an easy way to manipulate XML documents in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I have done a little research around the matter, but haven't really been able to come up with anything useful.  What I need is to not just parse and read, but actually manipulate XML documents in python, similar to the way JavaScript is able to manipulate HTML documents.

Allow me to give an example.  say I have the following XML document:

```
<library>
    <book id=123>
        <title>Intro to XML</title>
        <author>John Smith</author>
        <year>1996</year>
    </book>
    <book id=456>
        <title>XML 101</title>
        <author>Bill Jones</author>
        <year>2000</year>
    </book>
    <book id=789>
        <title>This Book is Unrelated to XML</title>
        <author>Justin Tyme</author>
        <year>2006</year>
    </book>
</library>
```

I need a way both to retrieve an element, either using XPath or with a "pythonic" method, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106480/really-simple-way-to-deal-with-xml-in-python), but I also need to be able to manipulate the document, such as below:

```
>>>xml.getElement('id=123').title="Intro to XML v2"
>>>xml.getElement('id=123').year="1998"
```

If anyone is aware of such a tool in Python, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: `minidom` might be considered slow, but it is readable and resembles JavaScript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) allows you to select elements using XPath, and also manipulate those elements.

```py
import lxml.etree as et

xmltext = """
<root>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <fruit>pear</fruit>
    <fruit>mango</fruit>
    <fruit>kiwi</fruit>
</root>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xmltext)

for fruit in tree.xpath('//fruit'):
    fruit.text = 'rotten %s' % (fruit.text,)

print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

**Result:**

```
<root>
    <fruit>rotten apple</fruit>
    <fruit>rotten pear</fruit>
    <fruit>rotten mango</fruit>
    <fruit>rotten kiwi</fruit>
</root>
```

Comment: when attempting this, I get an error on `import lxml.etree as et`, saying that there is `No module named lxml.etree`

Comment: lxml is not part of the standard library, you need to [install it](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

Comment: Also check out [lxml.objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) -- a great, different way to deal with the tree...

Comment: can you explain how to install lxml?  I have attempted following the instruction on the web page with absolutely no success.  I am running Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Just install using the relevant executable from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3

Answer (score 15):

If you want to avoid installing `lxml.etree`, you can use [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library.

Here is [Acorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967082/is-there-an-easy-way-to-manipulate-xml-documents-in-python/7967206#7967206) ported to `xml.etree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et  # was: import lxml.etree as et

xmltext = """
<root>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <fruit>pear</fruit>
    <fruit>mango</fruit>
    <fruit>kiwi</fruit>
</root>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xmltext)

for fruit in tree.findall('fruit'): # was: tree.xpath('//fruit')
    fruit.text = 'rotten %s' % (fruit.text,)

print et.tostring(tree) # removed argument: prettyprint
```

**note:**  I would have put this as a comment on Acorn's answer if I could have done so in a clear manner.  If you like this answer, give the upvote to Acorn.

Comment: does `xml.etree` a method for parsing the tree with xpath?

Comment: ElementTree only supports a subset of XPath.