# How to parse an XML file using Python?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to print all the elements and attributes in an xml file. The xml file's contents are:

```
<topology>
<switch id="10">
    <port no="1">h1</port>
    <port no="2">h2</port>
</switch>

<tunnel id="91">
<port no="1">s1</port>
<port no="8">s8</port>
</tunnel>
</topology>
```

How do I do it? Also, how do I search for an element like switch inside topology?

Comment: Step 1 search.  Python has several XML parsers already in the standard library. http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html  What part of the standard library documentation is hard to read?  Please choose one of the existing XML parsers, and follow the examples.  When you get stuck, please ask a **specific** question about the parser your chose.

Comment: That's a stilly question.  There are several.  They have different purposes.  I've used them all.  Please **Read** the documentation first before asking silly questions.

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/11/12/python-parsing-xml-with-minidom/). It should be simple and clear.

Comment: @Bruce: Clearly.  And I resent that.  There's a lot to learn, and you need to actually learn it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really simple way to deal with XML in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106480/really-simple-way-to-deal-with-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like S.Lott expressed, you have way too many ways to skin this cat,

**here is an example using**
[lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html),

```
from lxml import etree

xml_snippet = '''<topology>
 <switch id="10">
     <port no="1">h1</port>
     <port no="2">h2</port>
 </switch>

 <tunnel dpid="91">
 <port no="1">s1</port>
 <port no="8">s8</port>
 </tunnel>
 </topology>'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml_snippet)

for element in root.iter("*"):
  print element.tag, element.items()
```

**output:**

```
topology []
switch [('id', '10')]
port [('no', '1')]
port [('no', '2')]
tunnel [('dpid', '91')]
port [('no', '1')]
port [('no', '8')]
```

**Using XPath to find an attribute**

```
attribute = '10'
element = root.find('.//switch[@id="%s"]' % attribute)
element.items()
```

**output:**

```
[('id', '10')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my working code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse("nm.xml")
s = doc.find("switch")
print s.attrib["id"]
for item in s:
  print item.attrib["no"]
  print item.text

t = doc.find("tunnel")
print t.attrib["dpid"]
for item in t:
  print item.attrib["no"]
  print item.text
```

P.S: 
You can replace ET.parse with ET.fromstring and change input argument to a string type
It works